# Index In the *ngFor is not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have this Ionic 3 code where I have a loop with *ngFor but when I am trying to print index for the loop  every time it is printing 0;

```
<ion-list-header *ngFor="let child of item.value[item.key]; let i = index" no-padding>

  <ion-item *ngIf="!child.children" ion-item detail-none class="child-item" text-wrap>
    <h2> 
      <ion-icon aria-label="bulb" 
                class="icon-pad icon icon-md icon-md-orange ion-md-bulb item-icon" 
                color="orange" 
                name="bulb" 
                ng-reflect-name="bulb" 
                role="img" 
                ng-reflect-color="orange"></ion-icon>   
      {{ child['layoutName'] }}
    </h2>
    <h2 *ngIf="statusArray[i]">on {{i}}</h2>
    <button ion-button item-right color="secondary" (click)='on(child,1)'>on</button>
    <button ion-button item-right color="danger" (click)='on(child,0)' >off</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list-header>
```

Comment: sorry * was taking it as code start in stackoverflow so I removed it now

Comment: Syntax is `*ngFor`.

Comment: @nitish please double check your code and edits.

Comment: why are you looping list? use *ngFor for ion-item

Comment: Can you provide us your .ts code or array where you want to looping.

Comment: I did sir this is the final one@Antoniossss

Comment: Now you should make a [mcve] to reproduce your issue. If you can't, it means you made a typo.

Comment: my list has two values Its printing all other this properly only index its printing 0 always

Comment: @nitish since you are using it as array index `statusArray[i]`, you either should see duplicated entry, or `i` is counting just fine and you don't want to admint you overlooked it.

Comment: if you see the statement *ngIf='statsusArray[i]' that means it contains boolean if it contains false if wont display in the first place but I said It's displaying that means both are true value and I am also printing i directly still it's giving 0,0 @Antoniossss

Comment: @nitish no - it means that statusArray[i] is not undefined nor null nor false.

Comment: and still, eltier you got 2 times statusArray[0] or i is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Do following debug:

```
<ion-list-header ngFor="let child of item.value[item.key]; let i = index" no-padding>
{{i}} {{item.value[item.key] | json}}
```

What I think is that `item.value[item.key]` has only 1 element.

Comment: @nitish and {{i}} prints 0,0 ??:>

Comment: yeah @Antoniossss